# Do SteamVR headsets, like the HTC Vive, not work with A-Frame and WebVR or WebXR anymore?

Tags: aframe, webvr, htc-vive, webxr, steamvr

I have been struggling for a while to get my A-Frame scenes to display in my VR headset through SteamVR. Simply put, my goal is to find a way to get A-Frame projects to properly display on my headset, but instead my headset receives no feed from the A-Frame scene and displays a solid grey or black color. Here's the odd part: sometimes, I can get the A-Frame scene to show up on the SteamVR **VR View** window on my desktop, but when I put my headset on, the display is still greyed or blacked out. Unfortunately, no errors were encounter (so far) in the console log of the browser I tried running the A-Frame scenes in.

*Important* to mention, the HTC Vive Headset and OptiTrack Equipment do work. They work for Unity programs and other VR applications. They are just not working with WebVR, WebXR, and A-Frame programs.

Usually what occurs is when I open up the A-Frame scene in a web browser tab manually or by using http-server and ngrok, the scene runs fine on the desktop monitor. However, it then proceeds to open up SteamVR and attempts to connect to my headset. SteamVR will usually say **Playing Firefox** or **Playing Chrome**. Sometimes the A-Frame scene appears on the VR View of the SteamVR application, but every time I try this the headset display is blacked or greyed out. That's as far as I can get.

Equipment:

- HTC Vive Pro Eye (w/ OptiTrack Active Tag Attachment and Wireless Adapter)
- OptiTrack IR Cameras (not using base stations)
- HP Z4 Desktop Workstation Computer

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Enabling web xr and vr flags in browsers like Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, Edge, and Firefox Nightly (However, for browsers like Chrome, I couldn't find the web vr or xr flags anywhere)
- Disabling xr sandbox in the web browsers that provided the option to enable/disable xr sandbox
- Trying beta versions of SteamVR
- Using a mixed reality HP headset (The one that comes with the backpack VR computer) with Edge
- Trying different release versions of A-Frame
- Tried using Supermedium, which some have recommended, but I don't think opens A-Frame scenes...

I would paste error and code snippets, but for this scenario it wouldn't make sense since no errors pop up and it's very unlikely that the issue is from the HTML/JavaScript A-Frame code. Thank you for taking the time to read and consider this issue! If you need any other details I'll provide them here so just let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. There has been some glitches on the browsers transition to OpenXR. You might want to read https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4709 and add details about your issue.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos Thank you for this update! I will check this out.